# Unable to send file type to the server

Tags: php, android, image-uploading

When uploading an Image to a PHP server, I am sending it as a file this way:

```
entity.addPart("image_file", new FileBody(new File(file_path)));
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

But on the server side I get the error:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

because the data being sent is:

```
[image_file] => Array
    (
        [name] => IMG_20130801_124102.jpg
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => C:\wamp\tmp\php37E.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 2084727
    )
```

with no value for **type**.

It should be taking automatically as far as I know. Or should I set it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check the following things:

1. if the 'jpg' is set as allowed type in PHP config file.
2. if the image you are trying to upload exceeds 'upload_max_filesize' set in the php.ini file. You may test with a smaller image and see if it makes any changes.

Comment: Yeah I checked **1.** `$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';` **2. for size issues, I get a different message:** `The uploaded file exceeds the maximum allowed size in your PHP configuration file.`

Comment: Try this instead:

entity.addPart("image_file", new FileBody(new File(file_path), "image/jpeg"));